# How module can use resources of another module using gradle multi-module

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have Project A and project B

Project A unit-testings (under the tests dir) need to use resources files which under Projects B main/resources dir.

gradle.build on Project A:

```
dependencies {
..    testCompile project(':web')
}
```

gradle.build on Project B:

```
task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'resources'
    from sourceSets.main.resources
}
```

still failing.
i am not sure what am I missing?

Thank you,
ray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add a dependency on a project like this:

```
testCompile project(':B')
```

you're depending on the default artifact produced by project B, which is usually the default jar. If you want to depend on a custom jar, something like a test jar, or a resource jar, or a fat jar instead, you have to explicitly specify that. You can add custom artifacts to configurations, and depend on the configuration instead, as shown below:

in B's build.gradle:

```
configurations {
  foo
}

task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier 'resources'
    from sourceSets.main.resources
}

artifacts {
  foo testJar
}
```

and then use it in A as:

```
dependencies{
    testCompile project(path: ':B', configuration: 'foo')
}
```

To verify, you can add this task to A:

```
task printClasspath()<<{
    configurations.testCompile.each{println it}
}
```

which prints:

```
${projectRoot}\B\build\libs\B-resources.jar
```

Comment: what would u modify if i wanted instead of taking resources of project B but it's test's resources?