# Using a spring-beans .xml file (in 'resources' folder) from a shared module with gradle multi module (subproject)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, spring-bean

(To assist with this question, I have github links at the bottom of this question)

I have (and am "starting with" the below gradle multiple module/project)

> settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'com.mycompany.myteam.myapp-rootProjectName'

include ':source:java:myapproot:myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one'
include ':source:java:myapproot:myapp-business-logic'
(maybe even a few that are purely .java/.class "code logic" libraries)
```

In the subproject:

> ':source:java:myapproot:myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one'

I have the typical Spring-Boot startup and a spring-bean setup using applicationContext.xml.

```
./source/java/myapproot/myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one/src/main/java/demo/SpringBootApplicationContextXmlConsoleApplication.java
--
./source/java/myapproot/myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml
./source/java/myapproot/myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one/src/main/resources/orch.one.di.xml
./source/java/myapproot/myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one/src/main/resources/clientporxy.one.di.xml
```

The contents of "applicationContext.xml" are below.
Note, it has a "pointer" 'import' entries to some other .xml files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <import resource="orch.one.di.xml"/>

    <import resource="clientproxy.one.di.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Everything above works just fine.  I've been doing the above approach for years and for many different projects.

============================================================

What I am trying to do is put the 2 "extra" *.di.xml files in **another** gradle module.

> settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'com.mycompany.myteam.myapp-rootProjectName'

include ':source:java:myapproot:myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one'
include ':source:java:myapproot:myapp-business-logic'

    (new one below)
include ':source:java:myapproot:myapp-shared-resxex'
```

And I want to move the *.di.xml files to this different/new gradle-subproject/module. (':source:java:myapproot:myapp-shared-resxex' to be clear)

So now I have moved the two *.di.xml files.

File location is here: (under "resources")

```
./source/java/myapproot/myapp-shared-resxex/src/main/resources/orch.one.di.xml
./source/java/myapproot/myapp-shared-resxex/src/main/resources/clientproxy.one.di.xml
```

So now when I start the "main" application, I get errors like below (and I kinda expected these errors)

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 

    ./source/java/myapproot/myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one/build/resources/main/clientproxy.one.di.xml

    (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:333)
```

I have "tried" (and worked through) things like these:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html

[Gradle: common resource dependency for multiple java projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136214/gradle-common-resource-dependency-for-multiple-java-projects)

[How module can use resources of another module using gradle multi-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699308/how-module-can-use-resources-of-another-module-using-gradle-multi-module)

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-bundle-static-resources-from-other-subproject-into-java-application/42076

Like many days and many hours been trying to figure out the magic-sauce.

So, my "in general" question is

**How can I get a spring bean .xml file to work from a different gradle-subproject/module?**

I will show my latest attempt:

> ./source/java/myapproot/myapp-shared-resxex/build.gradle

```
configurations {
    myCoolConfigurationName
}

task tryToPackageStuffForOtherSubprojectsTask(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier
    from sourceSets.main.resources
}

artifacts {
    myCoolConfigurationName tryToPackageStuffForOtherSubprojectsTask
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(':source:java:myapproot:clientproxies:myclientproxy-root:myclientproxy-domain')
    implementation project(':source:java:myapproot:clientproxies:myclientproxy-root:myclientproxy-interfaces')
    implementation project(':source:java:myapproot:clientproxies:myclientproxy-root:myclientproxy-concrete')


}
```

and then:

> ./source/java/myapproot/myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "application"
}

apply plugin : "java"

ext {
    javaMainClass = "demo.SpringBootApplicationContextXmlConsoleApplication"
}

application {
    mainClassName = javaMainClass
}


task myCustomPrintClasspathTask  {
    doLast {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.each { println 'helloThere->' + it }
    }
}


dependencies {

    //the below line, if left not-commented-out, will produce a warning : "Execution optimizations have been disabled for task"
    implementation project(path: ':source:java:myapproot:myapp-shared-resxex', configuration: 'myCoolConfigurationName')


    implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: springBootVersion) {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }

    implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: springBootVersion) {
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }

    implementation project(":source:java:myapproot:myapp-shared-resxex")
    implementation project(':source:java:myapproot:myapp-business-logic')

    implementation project(':source:java:myapproot:clientproxies:myclientproxy-root:myclientproxy-domain')
    implementation project(':source:java:myapproot:clientproxies:myclientproxy-root:myclientproxy-interfaces')
    implementation project(':source:java:myapproot:clientproxies:myclientproxy-root:myclientproxy-concrete')


    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: commonsLangVersion
    implementation group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: "${javaxInjectVersion}"

    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: slf4jSimpleVersion

    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: mockitoVersion

}
```

When I run (a clean build and then) the custom task:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build
$ ./gradlew myCustomPrintClasspathTask
```

I get the below output:

```
> Task :source:java:myapproot:myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one:myCustomPrintClasspathTask

helloThere->./source/java/myapproot/myapp-shared-resxex/build/libs/myapp-shared-resxex.jar

helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.7.5/c28e1546461803490588085345ba5d2897d232bc/spring-boot-starter-2.7.5.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.7.5/96646e63a2296d0a3209383e81cdb8c87ab2f913/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.5.jar
helloThere->./source/java/myapproot/myapp-business-logic/build/libs/myapp-business-logic.jar
helloThere->./source/java/myapproot/clientproxies/myclientproxy-root/myclientproxy-concrete/build/libs/myclientproxy-concrete.jar
helloThere->./source/java/myapproot/clientproxies/myclientproxy-root/myclientproxy-interfaces/build/libs/myclientproxy-interfaces.jar
helloThere->./source/java/myapproot/clientproxies/myclientproxy-root/myclientproxy-domain/build/libs/myclientproxy-domain.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/c6842c86792ff03b9f1d1fe2aab8dc23aa6c6f0e/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.inject/javax.inject/1/6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38/javax.inject-1.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.36/a41f9cfe6faafb2eb83a1c7dd2d0dfd844e2a936/slf4j-simple-1.7.36.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.7.5/61f4c53e35baa31a269bbeb7bb9d5e781448feef/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.5.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.2/17dd0fae2747d9a28c67bc9534108823d2376b46/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.36/ed46d81cef9c412a88caef405b58f93a678ff2ca/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/6c62681a2f655b49963a5983b8b0950a6120ae14/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.7.5/fd04e228e6e21b7ad13c10ae29afd31868d842e5/spring-boot-2.7.5.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/59eb84ee0d616332ff44aba065f3888cf002cd2d/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.3.23/530b36b2ce2c9e471c6a260c3f181bcd20325a58/spring-context-5.3.23.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.3.23/30d0034ba29178e98781d85f51a7eb709a628e9b/spring-aop-5.3.23.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.3.23/3bdefbf6042ed742cbe16f27d2d14cca9096a606/spring-beans-5.3.23.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.3.23/3a676bf4b9bc42bd37ab5ad264acb6ceb63397a2/spring-expression-5.3.23.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.3.23/91407dc1106ea423c44150f3da1a0b4f8e25e5ca/spring-core-5.3.23.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.30/8fde7fe2586328ac3c68db92045e1c8759125000/snakeyaml-1.30.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.23/3c7eb5fcca67b611065f73ff4325e398f8b051a3/spring-jcl-5.3.23.jar
helloThere->/Users/MyDomainUserName/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.17.2/f42d6afa111b4dec5d2aea0fe2197240749a4ea6/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar
```

If I "peek" into the jar:

> ./source/java/myapproot/myapp-shared-resxex/build/libs/myapp-shared-resxex.jar

I do see the two *.di.xml files.

and then if I run:

```
$ ./gradlew run
```

I continue to get:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./source/java/myapproot/myapp-toplayer-console-di-xml-one/build/resources/main/clientproxy.one.di.xml (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:333)
        ... 32 more
```

My ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file (for completeness and to know my gradle-version)

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

.....

Github repo with the code.

https://github.com/granadacoder/gradle-multi-with-spring-bean-proof

"main" branch...has a working spring-bean di.xml setup.
"main" branch relates to my comment above "everything above works just fine".

I have a second branch (and a PR so you can see the "diff").

branch:

https://github.com/granadacoder/gradle-multi-with-spring-bean-proof/tree/feature/move-spring-bean-xml-files-try-1

and PR (from the feature branch to the main branch to show the "diff")

https://github.com/granadacoder/gradle-multi-with-spring-bean-proof/pull/2/files

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I found an "old" documentation page.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s07.html

I'll post the quote from the above URL, in case it "disappears"..  especially since it is "old" documentation.

//START ARTICLE QUOTE

> 4.7.2.2 The classpath*: prefix When constructing an XML-based application context, a location string may use the special classpath*:
> prefix:
>
> ApplicationContext ctx =
> new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:conf/appContext.xml"); This
> special prefix specifies that all classpath resources that match the
> given name must be obtained (internally, this essentially happens via
> a ClassLoader.getResources(...) call), and then merged to form the
> final application context definition.
>
> [Note]    Classpath*: portability The wildcard classpath relies on the
> getResources() method of the underlying classloader. As most
> application servers nowadays supply their own classloader
> implementation, the behavior might differ especially when dealing with
> jar files. A simple test to check if classpath* works is to use the
> classloader to load a file from within a jar on the classpath:
> getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("").
> Try this test with files that have the same name but are placed inside
> two different locations. In case an inappropriate result is returned,
> check the application server documentation for settings that might
> affect the classloader behavior.
>
> The "classpath*:" prefix can also be combined with a PathMatcher
> pattern in the rest of the location path, for example
> "classpath*:META-INF/*-beans.xml". In this case, the resolution
> strategy is fairly simple: a ClassLoader.getResources() call is used
> on the last non-wildcard path segment to get all the matching
> resources in the class loader hierarchy, and then off each resource
> the same PathMatcher resoltion strategy described above is used for
> the wildcard subpath.

//END ARTICLE QUOTE

So I had forgotten about the "string-magic" of using classpath (before file-names, etc).

I was able to update my applicationContext.xml file to the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <!-- below are "imports" to OTHER (spring-bean) di.xml files -->

    <import resource="classpath:clientproxy.one.di.xml"/>

    <import resource="classpath*:orchestrators.one.di.xml"/>



</beans>
```

You can read about the difference between using the "*" (after classpath) in the below SOF question/answers.

[Spring classpath prefix difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294423/spring-classpath-prefix-difference)

For clarity....all I did was "move" the two di.xml files to the "other" gradle/module-subproject.  I did not use any of the "myCoolConfigurationName" stuff I showed in my original question ... as one of my "tries".

"so simple"........I was happy and in disbelief with my days of struggle with this.....